# ServiceStack IAuthWithRequest

Tags: asp.net-core, servicestack

I’m getting confused about implementing a CustomAuthProvider that extends the IAuthWithRequest interface. 
The wish is for this AuthProvider to recover domain credentials and authenticate against a third party service. From the documentation I read that, in this case, each HTTP request triggers the authentication process, with the consequence of triggering each time the creation of a new session and the saving of permissions / roles, an operation that can be expensive. 
Two questions: 
 1. What is the best way to store information between HTTP calls? 
 2. It’s more correct to use IAuthEvents
    interface events than CustomUserAuthSession events right?

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For a CredentialsAuthProvider that implements [IAuthWithRequest Auth Provider](https://docs.servicestack.net/authentication-and-authorization#authentication-per-request-auth-providers) have a look at [BasicAuthProvider](https://github.com/ServiceStack/ServiceStack/blob/main/ServiceStack/src/ServiceStack/Auth/BasicAuthProvider.cs) which implements [HTTP Basic Auth](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Basic_access_authentication).

You can store info between HTTP Calls in your own Cookies or using [ServiceStack's Session Bag](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#using-dynamic-untyped-sessions-in-session-bag).

Overriding the [Session callbacks](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#session-events) or registering [Auth Events](https://docs.servicestack.net/sessions#auth-events) is just a matter of preference.

Whether to use

Comment: Thank @mythz. If you use SessionBag, what is its lifecycle?

Comment: @w4rcT it’s stored in the registered ICacheClient without a TTL so however long before the cache is flushed

Comment: Thank you very much, always very exhaustive @mythz